# Convert intervals query to the earlier version that doesn't support it

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have an ES query that was written in a newer version of ES that supports `intervals` query.
But I want to convert this simple query that has `intervals` in it to the query to run on the earlier version of 6 that doesn't support `intervals`

```
GET /myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "intervals": {
            "title_en": {
              "match": {
                "query": "title phrase in en",
                "max_gaps": -1,
                "ordered": true
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "intervals": {
            "title_de": {
              "match": {
                "query": "title phrase in de",
                "max_gaps": -1,
                "ordered": true
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match" : 1,
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {"status.id": [1,2]}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I think I should solve it with `query_string`.
I write something like this(part of it):

```
{
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "title_en",
      "query": "\"title phrase in en\"~3"
    }
}
```

But I think it's not the correct solution.

Comment: Which version do you use?

Comment: I need to run it on version 6.2.2

Comment: Is there any idea how to remove intervals query and convert it?

Answer (score 0):

The following query allows getting results similar to `intervals`.

`intervals` are replaced with `match_phrase` and `slop` is used.

`slop` value can be configured to allow us to control how many words can be placed between query words.

So query is:

```
GET /myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "title_en": {
              "query": "title phrase in en",
              "slop": 5
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "title_de": {
              "query": "title phrase in de",
              "slop": 5
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match" : 1,
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {"status.id": [1,2]}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```